# Vimeo showing processing error when video uploaded from server to vimeo site using php

Tags: php, ios, video, vimeo-api

I am uploading video from my ios application to server using php webservice.After successful upload i am trying to upload it on vimeo.Vimeo site give us video link url but that url is not working. If i am going to the vimeo site and check the video, then its showing as processing error. here is the screen shot

[image]

I am using the php vimeo api lib https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

Here is my php webservice function which i am using in my ios application

```
include_once './autoload.php';
use Vimeo\Vimeo;

function saveVideoDetails($postData, $con)
{
    $client_id = "ClientId";
    $client_secret = "ClientSecret";
    $toke_secret = "TokenSecret";

    $lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $toke_secret);
    $userId = $postData->user_id;
    $videoTitle = addslashes(validateValue($postData->video_title, "Untitled"));
    $videoDescription = addslashes(validateValue($postData->video_description, "No description"));
    $videoEncodedData = $postData->video_encodedData;
    $videoThumbImageData = $postData->video_thumbImageData;
    $videoDuration = $postData->video_Duration;

    $errorMsg = "";

    $uploadDir = IMAGE_UPLOADFOLDER;
    $uploadvdoDir =VIDEO_UPLOADFOLDER;

    $vdoThubName = date('dMYHsa_') . "uid_" . $userId . "_thumb.png";
    $vdoName = date('dMYHsa_') . "uid_" . $userId . "_video.mp4";

    $videoThumbLink = $uploadDir . $vdoThubName;
    $videoLink = $uploadvdoDir . $vdoName;

    if (strlen($videoEncodedData) > 0)
    {
        $binary = base64_decode($videoEncodedData);
        $file = fopen($videoLink,'wb') or die("open failed----> ".$videoLink);
        $P=fwrite($file, $binary);
        if($P)
        {
            fclose($file);
                $urlink =$videoLink;
                $video_response = $lib->request('/me/videos', array('type' => 'pull', 'link' => $urlink), 'POST');
                $vimeo_video_link = $video_response['body']['link'];
                if(!$vimeo_video_link)
                {
                    $status = 3;
                    $errorMsg = "Video upload fail in vimeo";
                }
                else
                {
                   $status = 1;
                    $errorMsg = "Video uploaded";
                }   
        }
        else
        {
            $status = 3;
            $errorMsg = "unable to upload";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $status = 2;
        $errorMsg = "video data not available";
    }
    $data['status'] = $status;
    $data['message'] = $errorMsg;
    $data['data'] = null;
    return $data;  
}
```

Comment: Can you reach out to Vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact and provide links to the videos with processing errors?

Answer (score 0):

As such in your code there is no issue.

You need to check vimeo exceptions.
Before that **please make sure whatever video URL you are passing as a parameter in vimeo request is correct or not.** If it is nil or incorrect then vimeo gives error as invalid file.

```
$urlink =$videoLink; 
$video_response = $lib->request('/me/videos', array('type' => 'pull', 'link' => $urlink), 'POST'); 
$vimeo_video_link = $video_response['body']['link'];
```

In above code please check variable   **$urlink** is proper or not.

Also according to vimeo terms if you are using free account than we can upload 10 video per day. So if you exceed this limit then also you can not upload video.

To read vimeo terms https://vimeo.com/help/faq/vimeo-membership/vimeo-plus

In vimeo API library (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php) which you already used there is one file for exception so you can use that file to check exception.

Comment: Yes,I am using free account of vimeo and i caught the exception - 10 video per day allowed.Thanks